# extracting between two patterns in sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Input text file:

```
#END
this should not be extracted
#BEGIN    
This should be extracted.
#BEGIN
keep going..
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
#END
That should be all.
#BEGIN
Nothing from here.
#END
```

Desired output:

```
This should be extracted.
#BEGIN
keep going..
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

My sed script is:

```
/#BEGIN/,/#END/!d
/#END/q
/#BEGIN/,/#END/{/#BEGIN/d;/#END/d;p;}
```

My script can do most of what I want it to do except for ignore the first #END and print whatever is in the first #BEGIN #END block (including the nested #BEGIN). I am not sure how to change my script in order to meet these constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^#BEGIN/,/^#END/!b;//!p;/^#END/q' file
```

Limit the lines printed to between `#BEGIN` and `#END` and only print the non header/footer lines. Quit when hitting the first `#END`.

N.B. Placing the regexp for quitting following the print command allows the second or more headers to remain in the output.

Comment: This works nicely except for if I had the line: "There is no #END line to terminate the printing" in my input, this script does not print that line. It should ignore any #END or #BEGIN that is not the first word (column) of a sentence.

Comment: thanks, this works! Just so I understand it better - what is the "!b" doing? I am not sure what "b" is in sed. Thanks.

Comment: @asddddddaaaad2 Notice that the `-b` option is activated. This makes sed act like grep, in that printing will only occur if the commands `p` or `P` are present in the sed script. The `!b` means if the previous address is not matched jump over any following instructions and read a new line and begin a new cycle of commands.